# Bootstrap 4 two rows fixed menu

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, row, navbar

I'm trying to achieve this result with BS 4.0 Beta:

[image]

I have my default navbar.
But I couldn't manage to put the topbar on top with the fixed top navbar.
They must be fixed on top when scrolling the page.
Plus, should I use the BS hide and show feature to organize it when collapse?

I'm kinda lost here.

```
<!-- Topbar-->
<div class="container-fluid fixed-top">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 text-left">
      <i class="fas fa-angle-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>     mail@website.com
</div>
<div class="col-sm-6 text-right">
    <i class="fas fa-angle-right" aria-hidden="true"></i> +55 00 0000-0000
</div>
</div>
</div>
<!-- Navbar -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light navbar-main">
  <div class="container">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">
      <img src="/images/logo.svg" class="img-fluid" alt="ENGINE">
    </a>
<button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
  <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
</button>
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
  <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="/">Home</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Empresa</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Serviços</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Sistemas</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Planos</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Contato</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
</div>
</nav>
```

Any help is welcome!
Thanks!

Comment: Did you look at any of the similar questions? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48773669/bootstrap-4-multiple-fixed-navbars-with-animated-shrink/48774705, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42417018/bootstrap-4-multiple-fixed-top-navbars/42418583, and this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48904112/place-fixed-top-elements-above-one-another-bootstrap-4/48904509, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42635126/bootstrap-4-navbar-with-2-rows

Comment: Here's [an example](https://www.codeply.com/go/VxP5otyw2q) adapted from the duplicate answer.